# Why does Object.fromEntries(formData) work

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data, iterable

1. I've got a form.
2. I listen when user submit it.
3. I make a new instance of the FormData class.

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form);
  });
```

I know that `formData.entries()` will return an iterable, so i can use a `for of` loop to get the pairs... What i don't get is why this actually works:

`const pairValues = Object.fromEntries(formData);`

`formData` is an instance of a class that HAS multiple methods. Is not an iterable itself.

Does Object.fromEntries looks for an iterator by default?

Comment: "*Is not an iterable itself.*" why do you think it isn't? "*Does Object.fromEntries looks for an iterator by default?*" that **is** what an iterable is - an object that has an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a `FormData` object has a `Symbol.iterator` method, which makes it iterable.

You can check and see that:

```
formData[Symbol.iterator] === formData.entries
```

They are the same function.

Now `Object.fromEntries(form)` accepts an iterable, as also [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#parameters) documents:

> #### Parameters
>
> `iterable`
>
> An iterable such as `Array` or `Map` or other objects implementing the iterable protocol.

So `Object.fromEntries` will invoke `formData[Symbol.iterator]`, which is the same as calling `formData.entries`.